# __toString() must return a string value when submitting a form

Tags: forms, entity, symfony, tostring

I have an show view that I had to custom a little bit so we can edit things in it. Among these things there is a multi select that is the result of a query to filter schools I've done inside the controller, sent via the render method.

Before all that, I was using a many-to-many multi select form to select every schools ever saved in the database. Now I want to use it so I can use what's already working.

Since it's sent via the render and not the form, I managed to create an HTML form, to display it, and to get to see what has been selected when I submit the form, however I had several problems:

First of all, it wanted to be an instance of an object, and to be able to save an object instead of an array. I managed to do that by doing the following:

```
        $object = new Ecole();
        foreach ($ecolesDispo as $key => $value)
        {
            $object->$key = $value;
        }
        $mission->addEcolesDispo($object);
```

(Ecole is for schools)

The problem I'm now stuck with came right after it, because now it wants it to be converted to string, however, I can't manage to do so.

Here's how the concerned part of my entity looks like.

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ecolesDispo = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->addEcolesDispo($object);
//Not sure about that part though
}

/**
 * Add ecolesDispo
 *
 * @param \EcoleBundle\Entity\Ecole $ecolesDispo
 *
 * @return Mission
 */
public function addEcolesDispo(\EcoleBundle\Entity\Ecole $ecolesDispo)
{
    $this->ecolesDispo[] = $ecolesDispo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove ecolesDispo
 *
 * @param \EcoleBundle\Entity\Ecole $ecolesDispo
 */
public function removeEcolesDispo(\EcoleBundle\Entity\Ecole $ecolesDispo)
{
    $this->ecolesDispo->removeElement($ecolesDispo);
}

/**
 * Get ecolesDispo
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getEcolesDispo()
{
    return $this->ecolesDispo;
}
```

How can I convert this to string?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What Entity is that, is it a Mission Entity? Also, can you show the Ecole Entity code? What exactly to you want to show with the `__toString()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Your **__toString** function should looks like :

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->id; // Because __toString seems to be called to set your $key variable...
}
```

-> rely on a string property.

In your __toString() function, you use `(string)` which will implicitely call ... `__toString()` to convert `$this` to a string. That would be a circular call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if there's a string variable **name** in the entity where you were using __toString or use any string type property of that entity which specifies the entity itself.

```
public function __toString()
{
    // Or change the property that you want to show 
    return $this->name; 
}
```